# Unknown Inner Query Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the script below throwing an error on the inner query. I use Sequel Pro and am only getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Savings
>   FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
>   LEFT JOIN Projects p
>   ON osh.OfferI' at line 2

So I'm uncertain as to what the actual issue is. I tried doing an explicit inner join within the inner query in case the `p` alias wasn't being referenced/interpreted properly or something similar, but that had no positive effect.

```
SELECT SUM(osh.Savings) as YTD, 
   SUM (SELECT Savings
FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
LEFT JOIN Projects p
ON osh.OfferID = p.offer_id
WHERE p.uid = 1 AND p.current_status < 3) 
   AS "Open Savings"
FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
LEFT JOIN Projects p
    ON p.offer_id = osh.OfferID
WHERE p.uid = '1'
```

Any help is appreciated. Best,

Comment: Are you sure you can apply `SUM()` to a subquery?

Comment: Nope, wasn't sure at all! Didn't think to simply move it over, though. A little Occam's Razor below did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write the query much more simply as:

```
SELECT SUM(osh.Savings) as YTD,
       SUM(case when p.current_status < 3 then Savings end) AS "Open Savings"
FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh LEFT JOIN
     Projects p
     ON p.offer_id = osh.OfferID
WHERE p.uid = '1'
```

That is, you can replace the subquery entirely with a conditional summation.

Comment: thanks. I had something similar, but when speaking w/ a buddy who works a lot in SQL he mentioned `CASE` being heavier than an inner query. Is this not so, or just not for MySQL?

Comment: @JohnBlythe . . . I cannot think of a circumstance in any database that I'm familiar with where the subquery would perform better than this version. Off-hand, I can't even think of an architecture for the engine  where that would be possible.  Either your buddy is wrong or you misunderstood him.

Comment: gotcha. just spoke w/ him again and he agreed that `case` would be best now that I had explained the situation even further. Thanks!

Comment: I've got a problem related to an expanded version of this fix. Is it appropriate for me to post here? Or should I start a new thread for it?

Comment: @JohnBlythe . . . I think it is better to ask a new question, once you have answers to an existing one.  It can make the existing answers (and there are five of them) look really out of touch, if they are no longer suitable to the question.

Comment: truth. thanks. in case you're curious/interested, here it is :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101360/incorrect-sum-after-joining

Answer (score 1):

you cant make sum (select ....) .

try this

```
 SELECT SUM(osh.Savings) as YTD, 
       (SELECT SUM(Savings)
       FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
       LEFT JOIN Projects p
       ON osh.OfferID = p.offer_id
       WHERE p.uid = 1 AND p.current_status < 3) 
 AS "Open Savings"
 FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
 LEFT JOIN Projects p
 ON p.offer_id = osh.OfferID
 WHERE p.uid = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this can be simplified with `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(osh.Savings) as YTD, 
   SUM (CASE WHEN p.current_status < 3 THEN Savings ELSE 0 END) AS "Open Savings"
FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
    INNER JOIN Projects p
        ON osh.OfferID = p.offer_id
WHERE p.uid = 1
```

Also, there is no need for the `LEFT JOIN since you're restricting your results to p.uid=1.

Comment: isn't `CASE` more intensive on resources?

Comment: @JohnBlythe -- nope, this should be your most efficient solution :)  Best of luck!  Correlated subqueries are very expensive.

Comment: interesting. is that mysql specific, or in general? and can you expound on the resource expenditures between the two? n00b here :)

Comment: @JohnBlythe -- No, that should work in any RDBMS.  Take a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/592c1/5 -- you can see the execution plan for both queries.  Using CASE only requires a single lookup, where as the subquery requires multiple.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: @JohnBlythe -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing a SUM over a SELECT and not viceversa.
This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(osh.Savings) as YTD, 
    (SELECT SUM(Savings)
FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
LEFT JOIN Projects p
ON osh.OfferID = p.offer_id
WHERE p.uid = 1 AND p.current_status < 3) 
   AS "Open Savings"
FROM OfferSuggestionHeader osh
LEFT JOIN Projects p
    ON p.offer_id = osh.OfferID
WHERE p.uid = '1'
```